# Creating new JCAPS eWays (like HL7, JMS, ...)

Tags: jakarta-ee, integration, jcaps

I'm wondering how, in JCAPS 6, we can create *new* eWays. By eWay, I mean the components like the existing HL7, JMS, File, eMails (ie, external applications) ... I am not sure about the exact name of these entites, "API oriented OTD", JBI, JCA.

Basically, I would like to create an object that:
- is part of the Connectivity Map
- has properties (which can be overwritten in Glassfish)
- can cooperate dynamically with my Collaborations (JCDs)

Does anyone know how to create such objects?

Thanks, Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is the eWay Developement Kit (eDK). You can find the documentation [here](http://dlc.sun.com/pdf/819-7384/819-7384.pdf); and you should be able to find a file named "eWayDevelopmentKit.sar" in your adapters_ml\adapters JCAPS folder. Then unzip edk.zip, start runEDK.bat (adjust env.bat if necessary), and that's it !